# Easy absolute positioning in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning

For my presentaton slides I'd like to have list uncovered and highlighted by time and each item supported by appropriate image/graph/table.

Thinking about it in wider application, I'd like to find/create command:

```
\abspos{<anchor-spec>}{<coords>}{<content>}
```

where:

- `<anchor-spec>` specifies anchor point of positioned object. IE. NE for NorthEast corner point, etc.,
- `<coorrds>` specifies x-y-z coordinates on frame using standard LaTeX dimensions,
- `<content>` contain positioned graphics, table or text.

Idea of code for my purpose:

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
 \item<1-> Foo
 \item<2-> Bar
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\uncover<1>\abspos{C}{.5\textwidth,.5\textheight,1}{\includegraphics{foo}}
\uncover<2>\abspos{C}{.5\textwidth,.5\textheight,1}{\includegraphics{bar}}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: `z`? Are you able to project 3-dimensional PDFs?

Comment: In HTML/CSS you have also z-index although web pages are 2D. This `z` coordinate should define order of visibility of objects. That's why there's no dimension in my MWE (minimal wanted example)

Comment: Ah, very well, you may add that to your question, although, it might be the trickiest part. I don’t have time now, but I can see a solution with either [`pst-abspos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-abspos) or [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) and/or TikZ using the special `current page` node.

Comment: Something along the lines of `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics{foo}};` would do. The `z` part can be achieved by defining appropiate layers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok that's my try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz, etoolbox}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcount\mycount

\def\mytempcoord{}
\def\mytempopa{}
%
\newcommand\doatpos[3]{%
    \bgroup
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\ifnum\mycount<2
                        \edef\mytempcoord{\mytempcoord ##1%
                            \ifnum\mycount<1
                            ,
                            \fi
                        }
                        \else
                        \edef\mytempopa{##1}
                        \fi     
                        \advance\mycount by 1
                        }
    \docsvlist{#2}\global\advance\mycount by -3
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=#1, opacity=\mytempopa] at (\mytempcoord) {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
        %
    %
    \egroup
%
}


\begin{document}
\frame{
\doatpos{west}{0cm, 3cm,.5}{This is text \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\doatpos{west}{1cm, -3 cm,.7}{This is text a\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
}

\end{document}
```

I basically wrote a parser which divides this three item comma list in such a way that it can be used by an ordinary sequence like my TikZ overlay thing here. 
You might find that your third argument, the pseudo z-variable, needs no dimension. Well yes. Involving a certain key handler here could be useful. 
However, my opinion is different. I rather would introduce a new argument (in braces). That would make things much easier. (My very personal view is that mimicking the behavior of completely different systems is rather pointless.)

[image]

Same output, but no `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\def\mytemparray{}

%
\newcommand\doatpos[3]{%
    \bgroup
    \def\mytemparray{{ #2 }}
    \pgfmathparse{\mytemparray[0]} \edef\mya{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\mytemparray[1]} \edef\myb{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\mytemparray[2]} \edef\myc{\pgfmathresult} %also possible \pgfmathsetmacro
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node[anchor=#1, opacity=\myc] at ( \mya pt, \myb  pt) {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
        %
    %
    \egroup
%
}

\begin{document}
\frame{
    \doatpos{west}{0, 3 cm, .5}{This is text \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
    \doatpos{west}{1cm, -3 cm,.7}{This is text a\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
    }
\end{document}
```

This alternative uses `pgfmath` for list-processing. Since `pgfmathparse` is very expansion unfriendly i decided to hard-code and put those three elements in distinguished macros. This solution is again very specific and inflexible, but i think it's more obvious how to process more items in the list.

Comment: Very useful. I have tried this with images and it works great.