# beamer: grouping elements together

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am using beamer for creating my presentation. Sometime I create elementary objects (like geometrical shapes and arrows) by using tikzpicture and I place them in the slide by using textblock.

I would like to know if there is a way of bonding different elements together (like text, equations and geometrical objects), so that I can move them easily around the slide as one piece.

Comment: You can place them in a scope and give `[shift={(x,y)}]` option to the scope.

Comment: I think you should go a little bit more in detail: how freely you want to move your elements? Do you want to reuse those grouped objects more than once? And why is `textpos` not longer sufficient? This could be related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85269/easy-absolute-positioning-in-beamer

Answer (score 1):

The way I go about this usually is to compile such elements in a separate file, creating a PDF file which I can then put into the presentation via `\includegraphics`. It's especially convenient if you reuse the same illustration made up by several components more than once.

My minimum template example for such a figure file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The use of the `preview` package will crop the PDF to exactly the dimensions of the drawn picture. I am using `\sffamily` here because it mostly looks better for presentations, but depending on usage it could also be left out.