# Text end of the Line (Beamer)

Tags: beamer

I d like in my presentation a red (or pink) Text at the end of the slide completely to the right side **(HOS#13)**, like in the picture here:

[image]

I tried already with `\hfill` and

```
\begin{flushright}
  HOS#13
\end{flushright}
```

but I have really lots of error messages.

How can I get the same text in the same position??

Comment: Do you want this on a single frame or repeating?

Comment: Only on a single Slide, because on the other slides I m going to change the number after #. 
But it would be not so bad, if you both versions post :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi since the repeating solution i'm thinking of would require me to know which theme you are using (MWE) here's a versatile manual placement macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usepackage{tikz}
%some how stolen form here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85269/easy-absolute-positioning-in-beamer
\newcommand\doatpos[3]{%
    \bgroup%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[#1] at (#2) {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \egroup%
}

\begin{document}

\frame{
        \doatpos{anchor=south east, yshift=7mm}{current page.south east}{This is text }
          }

\end{document}
```