# Set permanent first bullet starting point in beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to set a permanent starting point for bullets in my Beamer slides. By default, the bullets are centered in the middle of the page. I have tried using the **[t]** option, but it places the first bullet at the very top of the page. I would like the bullet to start further down the page. Is there a way to set a specific starting point for the first bullet of every slide in a custom template?

An example of the roadblock I've run into is visible below using **[t]** in `/documentclass[t]{beamer}`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace{12pt}\color{DBlue}\bfseries\insertframetitle\par\vskip-25pt}
\definecolor{DBlue}{rgb}{.1,.1,.4}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TITLE FOO}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item foo1.
            \item foo2.
            \item foo3.
            \item foo4.
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first bullet "foo1" overlaps the title of the page. I'd like the bullet to start below the title. Is there a way to set all first bullets of a document class in a specific location? For example, 10mm down the page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: When i compiled your MWE i had problems with the second and third package you loaded. What is especially the second for? Anyways, after uncommenting these two lines all worked perfectly and without any overlaping. Regarding your question maybe try: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114861/is-something-the-first-item-on-a-page

Comment: I just added a photo of what I'm generating. The example code I posted is just a simple snippet of what I'm working with. I have a separate template which is configuring all of the settings so this is probably the reason it is not generating properly. However, that is unrelated as I just need a simple way to start the first bullet below the slide title.

Comment: You can manually place the entire contents of the `frame` inside a `minipage` of some fixed height...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Actually your code is not a MWE. I obtain the same that Ruben, so what is wrong here is just what you are not showing. Hardly we could help with this information.

Comment: I now have a MWE and updated snapshot.

Comment: This http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85269/easy-absolute-positioning-in-beamer might help. Just wrap a `minipage` around the `itemize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adapt your frametitle accordingly.   In your MWE you got a negative length causing the subsequent text to start right in the middle of the frametitle.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}    
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[default]

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace{12pt}\color{DBlue}\bfseries\insertframetitle%
  \par}%%gap between frametitle and text ist determined by the last lenght (or par) here 

\definecolor{DBlue}{rgb}{.1,.1,.4}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{TITLE FOO}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item foo1.
            \item foo2.
            \item foo3.
            \item foo4.
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Another solution could be obtained with [Easy absolute positioning in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85269/easy-absolute-positioning-in-beamer)